# Pip install fails with exit code 2 / error code 1 on fastlz module

Tags: python, c++, pip

When installing 'fastlz' from pip I'm encountering a Visual C++ error that I can't seem to decipher.  pip is running  the module's setup.py and encountering a compiler error "Exit Status 2"  then reports back that it encountered "Error Code 1".

Here's the output from the pip install :

```
C:\Python27\Scripts>pip install fastlz
Collecting fastlz
  Using cached fastlz-0.0.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: fastlz
  Running setup.py install for fastlz ... error
    Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools
, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\user1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-bnrzll\\
fastlz\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().
replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\user1\appd
ata\local\temp\pip-olbxjw-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-
managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    building 'fastlz' extension
    creating build
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\fastlz
    C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Pytho
n\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Ifastlz -Ic:\python27\
include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tcfastlz.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-2.7\Release\fastlz.obj
    fastlz.c
    fastlz.c(33) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(33) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(33) : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 302
arguments
    fastlz.c(37) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(40) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(50) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(64) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(64) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'ou
tput_len'
    fastlz.c(64) : error C2065: 'output_len' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(64) : error C2065: 'decompressed_len' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(69) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(69) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ')' before identifier 'in
put_len'
    fastlz.c(69) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(69) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
    fastlz.c(69) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
    fastlz.c(69) : warning C4552: '<' : operator has no effect; expected operato
r with side-effect
    fastlz.c(74) : error C2065: 'output_len' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(74) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(76) : error C2065: 'output_len' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(81) : error C2065: 'output_len' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(85) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(86) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(88) : error C2065: 'decompressed_len' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(88) : error C2065: 'uint32_t' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(88) : error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'fa
stlz_decompress'
    fastlz.c(89) : error C2065: 'output_len' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(91) : error C2065: 'decompressed_len' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(91) : error C2065: 'output_len' : undeclared identifier
    fastlz.c(100) : error C2065: 'output_len' : undeclared identifier
    error: command 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microso
ft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\
\users\\user1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-bnrzll\\fastlz\\setup.py';exec(c
ompile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), _
_file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\user1\appdata\local\temp\pip-olbxj
w-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" faile
d with error code 1 in c:\users\user1\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-bnrzll\fastl
z\
```

I can't seem to find out what these error codes mean.  Has anyone experienced this before, and know what I can do to fix these error 
codes?  Running the setup.py forms the same errors.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the author of fastlz? That person is the most like to understand the issues.

Comment: I can try, I think I might need to contact the person who created the pip fastlz wrapper though.  fastlz is a C compression library, but it appears as though the dev who made that didn't make the python wrapper available on pip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same issue (it's related to Visual Studio):

```
error: command 'C:\\Users\\user1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Common\\Microso
ft\\Visual C++ for Python\\9.0\\VC\\Bin\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

From control panel - fire up "add remove software" and select modify on Visual Studio - add C++ development. Wait for install to complete, reboot.